# Dereference-assignment to a doubly incremented OutputIterator

Tags: c++, iterator, increment, language-lawyer, post-increment

Per the (excellent) question [C++ OutputIterator post-increment requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876128/c-outputiterator-post-increment-requirements), we observe that for a dereferenceable and incrementable value `r` of `OutputIterator` type `X`, and value `o` of appropriate type, the expression

```
*r++ = o;
```

is valid and has equivalent semantics to

```
X a(r);
++r;
*a = o;
```

However, is it still the case the `a` is dereference-assignable if `r` has been incremented more than once in the intervening period; that is, is this code valid?

```
X a(r);
++r;
++r;
*a = o;
```

It's difficult to see how operations on a value can have an effect on the validity of operations on another value, but e.g. `InputIterator` (24.2.3) has, under the postconditions of `++r`:

> Any copies of the
>   previous value of `r` are no
>   longer required either to be
>   dereferenceable or to be in
>   the domain of `==`.

Relevant sections: **24.2.2 Iterator**, **24.2.4 Output iterators**, **17.6.3.1 Template argument requirements**.

Also, if this is *not* required to be valid, are there any situations where exploiting its non-validity would aid in the implementation (w.r.t. efficiency, simplicity) of an `OutputIterator` type while still observing the existing requirements?

Comment: SGI STL (http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/OutputIterator.html footnote 3) explicitly forbids this behavior, forcing a sequence of alternating increments and dereference-assignments; however, I can't derive that requirement from the C++ standard. Does '*only once*' in [24.2.4:2] mean exactly once or at most once?

Comment: This answer: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4004035/985943) makes me think that this behavior is valid for an `ostream_iterator`, which only actually increments on assignment, ignoring other increment operations. However, it doesn't seem all OutputIterators must obey those semantics.

Comment: @nknight very interesting. *only once* appears 5 times in the standard, at 3.4:1 with a different meaning, and at 5.17:7, 12.8:15, 29.6.5:8 in the sense *at most once (but usually once)*.  *exactly once* and *at most once* each appear 5 times.  Surely if the standard intended the SGI restrictions, they'd have incorporated that language?

Comment: Actually it looks like someone found this in 2004: (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#485), and the wording in n3066 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3066.html) seems to confirm the "alternating increment/dereference" requirement, don't you agree? Strange that this didn't make it into my copy of 14882:2011, when the rest of n3066 did (as far as I can tell).

Comment: @nknight and a little more digging reveals [defect 2035](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2035), which was raised after n3225 appeared without the fixes from n3066.  So the *intent* of the standard is clear, it just didn't get in to the published version in time.  Post as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was raised in 2004 as [defect 485](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#485), and the wording in [n3066](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3066.html) clarifies the issue, requiring that an output iterator need only support a sequence of alternating increments and dereference/assignments. So in your example, `r` need not be incrementable after the first `++r`, unless there is an intervening dereference/assignment. This behavior is also required by SGI's [STL](http://sgi.com/tech/stl/OutputIterator.html) (see footnote 3). As you mentioned above, n3225 appeared without the fixes from n3066, so [defect 2035](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2035) was raised; but alas the fix did not make it into the published version of C++11 (ISO/IEC 14882:2011).

Furthermore, defect 2035 says that `a` (from `X a(r++);`) cannot be used like `*a = 0`:

> "After this operation [i.e., `++r`] `r` is not required to be incrementable and any copies of the previous value of `r` are no longer required to be dereferenceable or incrementable."

There are situations where this may aid the implementation (in terms of *simplicity*): see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004035/985943) on `ostream_iterator`, where such (invalid) double increments are ignored simply returning `*this`; only a dereference/assignment causes the `ostream_iterator` to actually increment.